# Probability of the hottest summer day in 100 years

Tags: time-series, probability

I am trying to understand, what are the chances to have a 100-year temperature record for a day broken at least once during summer.

I am a stats noob, so my layman approach is this:

- There are 100 historical temperature readings for any given day.
- A probability of a day being the hottest for the last 100 years is
  $1/100$, or $0.01$.
- Therefore, a probability of the day being *not* the hottest one is $1
     - 0.01$, or $0.99$.

Based on this, I calculate the probability of having at least one hottest summer day in its 100-year measurement history as follows:
$1 - (0.99)^{92}$,  where 92 is the number of days in one summer.

The result is $\approx 60$, and this feels counterintuitive. Basically, it says that there is a 60% chance a temperature record for one of the summer days will be broken each year, which seems like a lot (climate change aside).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The calculation seems to assume statistical independence among the days, which I personally find uncanny.

Comment: I'd argue that the temperature on the same date in different years can be assumed independent, or close to that.

Comment: "Broken at least once" could be construed as "this summer has the highest max temp of all summers."  If you assume *summers* are independent without any trend, your original calculation is correct: every summer is equally likely to be the hottest.  But since weather follows some well-known cycles (driven by solar cycles), and there are only about nine cycles in a century, then a better estimate of this probability is around 1/9.  The moral is that such probability calculations are only as good as the assumptions that go into them.

Comment: Is there some distribution at play here? Like, an extremely hot/cold weather is less likely than a moderate weather, therefore my estimation of the hottest day in 100 years is not 1/100, but a lower value?

Comment: The point is not about distributions: *regardless* of the temperature distribution, the fundamental issue concerns the *independence* assumption, which just is not tenable.  A hot summer day is rarely followed by a cold winter day and only sometimes by a cool summer day, for instance.  Thus, you cannot legitimately proceed as if temperatures were like textbook rolls of the dice.